# Ansible : Failed to connect to the host via ssh : Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ssh, ansible, switch-statement

i'm new in ansible, i've installed it yesterday and i want to try to ping my remote host (hpe switch 5130).

I have an issue the host is unreachable and i don't know how to fix that.

[The config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S0Y0.png)

[Here is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbMmD.png)

[The host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzYfE.png)

The ssh works fine but i can't use ansible :(

Comment: Hi tristan Basbeaudou welcome to SO. Please don't post textual content as screenshots; it impairs searching, is hard to read, and is explicitly mentioned in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72360259/edit) and make the question legible. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

How do you ssh to your switch?
If you're using a password, add the "-k" option to the ansible command. It will ask you to enter your ssh password. Alternatively, set the ansible_password variable.

Also you should set some environment related vars, such as ansible_connection and ansible_network_os.